# mod rewrite - drupal style

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a website for a client, who would like NOT to use Drupal, but would like a Drupal-style mod rewrite (friendly url) feature on their website.

Having never created my own mod_rewrite engine before, are there any handy hints or tips you can give me? The CMS is totally created by me, and it would be nice to offer this feature, so if you could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: by engine, i mean, menu system, handler and htaccess file :)

Comment: I need a CMS, Writing content for my website shouldn't be a mess, I got a server with Apache but type with aimlessness, But I digress.

I need smart URLs, So all my content sells, Give me a hint, HEY!, Complete my sprint, HEY!

So I can rule this server space, space, space...

Rewrite Drupal stlye!

Drupal stlye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that to your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?argv=$1 [L]
```

and index.php/?argv=mypage will becomes /mypage then furthermore a php snippet to get the URI into an array

```
if($_GET['argv']){
  $argc = count($argv);
  $myURI = explode('/',$_GET['argv']);
  $controller = ($argc < 0) ?: $myURI[0];
  $action = (argc > 1) ? $myURI[1] : 'index';
  $params = (argc < 2) ?: array_slice($myURI, 2);
}
```

That's what I'm using on my mvc.

Comment: thanks, its christmas day, this looks like a gift ! ...  i'll implement it once the mulled wine and eggnog has left my system ..

Comment: I have slightly improve the snippet

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite Rewrite Rule generator will take a dynamic url given to it, and generate the correct syntax to place in a .htaccess file to allow the url to be rewritten in a spiderable format. The apache module "mod_rewrite" (which you need to enable) converts urls in a certain format to another format, and can be very useful in helping a site with dynamic content to be indexed.

```
Syntax: RewriteRule url-pattern url-new [[flag,...]]
Example: RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R,L]
```